# Still going through the IF STATEMENT even the value does not match in the value that I set

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I cannot find what could be the missing or error in my code, anyway I have created an `if else` statement where I can go to the first condition when:

`Variable One has a "N" value AND Variable Two or Variable Three has a "ValueOne"`
**OR**
`Variable One has a "N" AND Variable Four has a value of either "ValueTwo" or "ValueThree"`

Problem in my code is that it will go through to the first condition even there is no Value in Variable One as long as the Variable Four has the correct Value

The value that you will see in the code was not the actual value that I will be using it will be just an example.

I tried using this code to fix my problem:

```
function testNum() {
    var accessEquipment = "n";
    var sync = "sample1";
    var fiberServiceAlarm = "sample1";
    var wanLight = "flashingRed";
    var result1 = "success";
    var result2 = "fail";

    if (
        (accessEquipment == "n" && (sync == "sample" || fiberServiceAlarm == "sample")) ||
        (accessEquipment == "n" && (wanLight == "flashingGreen" || wanLight == "off" || wanLight == "flashingRed"))) {
        return result1;
    } else {
        return result2;
    }
}
```

This fix the problem but I think writing the code this way was not so good. Is there any way not to double the accessEquipment?

This is the actual code that I want to work:
Is there anything I need to add in this one?
In this one it still go to the IF STATEMENT event accessEquipment doesn't match the value that I set, as long as the wanLight has the flashingRed or the other values it still goes to the IF STATEMENT. What I want is that it only goes through there if the accessEquipment has N and wanLight has either of the three values.

```
function testNum() {
    var accessEquipment = "na";
    var sync = "sample1";
    var fiberServiceAlarm = "sample1";
    var wanLight = "flashingRed";
    var result1 = "success";
    var result2 = "fail";

    if (accessEquipment == "n"
        && (sync == "sample" || fiberServiceAlarm == "sample")
        || (wanLight == "flashingGreen" || wanLight == "off" || wanLight == "flashingRed")
    ) {
        return result1;
    } else {
        return result2;
    }
}
```

Comment: `'sample1'` !== `'sample'`. please check.

Comment: where should I put this? in the accessEquipment? if Yes I need it to go through in the if statement

Comment: i mean you have `'sample1'` in data and check `'sample'`. the result is quite unclear, because you take either an abstract approach in the description or a concrete in the code.

Comment: Yup, I intentionally did that so that it won't go through in the if statement, the problem is that once the wanLight has flashingRed or the other values it still go through even the accessEquipment has 'na'. What I want to happen is that it only go thru there is if n AND flashingRed. Sorry this is actually my first time asking questions here in stackoverflow

Comment: maybe a [table of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) may help and you get in idea of groupinmg some values.

Comment: base on my actual code.. accessEquipment = false , sync = false , fiberServiceAlarm = false , wanLight = true. so it should go to the else statement?

Comment: it would help, if you add in comments all possible values of the variables. then take the values and check the condition you need for either returning result one or two. xou need in this stage no optimizing. this can be done later, if the long version works.

Comment: the code that I tried to fix this works fine, but is there anyway to optimize that?

Comment: which one works the first or the second?

Comment: the first one, it works on how I wanted, but I think its a bad way of a writing a code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a more compact version by taking various values in an array and check with includes. This works for constant values as for variables.

```
function testNum() {
    var accessEquipment = "n";
    var sync = "sample1";
    var fiberServiceAlarm = "sample1";
    var wanLight = "flashingRed";
    var result1 = "success";
    var result2 = "fail";

    return accessEquipment == "n" && (
            [sync, fiberServiceAlarm].includes("sample") ||
            ["flashingGreen", "off", "flashingRed"].includes(wanLight)
        )
        ? result1
        : result2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to add one pair of parenthesses

```
if (accessEquipment == "n"
        && ((sync == "sample" || fiberServiceAlarm == "sample")
        || (wanLight == "flashingGreen" || wanLight == "off" || wanLight == "flashingRed")))
```

Comment: I set the accessEquipment to "na" so that it goes through the else statement, but what happens is that it still go through the if statement even though I set it to "na"

Comment: It's because you have this 

`accessEquipment == "n" && (...) || (wanLight ....)`

this translates to

`false && false || true` and this evaluates to `true`

Comment: what should I change for it to be evalutes to true only when the accessEquipment == "n" and wanLight is true?

Comment: `accessEquipment == "n" && (wanLight ...)`

Comment: so there is no other way for it to work unless I made it this way? accessEquipment ==  "n" && (wanLight...) || accessEquipment ==  "n" && (sync || fiberServiceAlarm)

Comment: `accessEquipment == "n" && ((wanLight...) || (sync || fiberServiceAlarm))` maybe this one is what you want

Comment: This perfectly works, but I wander why this is not working when wanLight and sync || fiberServiceAlarm switch positions

Comment: Now you can switch them, but you missed one pair or parenthesses --> `( (sync ...) || (wanLight ..) )` <--

Comment: well, I remember yesterday I tried putting those parentheses but still not working, well will try it when i come back to the office. Anyways Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to help, write here the result then ;)  :)